# show <ul> on checkbox click in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to show an  when a checkbox is checked. This is the code that I wrote in the HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Are you a musician?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul id="musicianField">
    <!-- Set List - Musician -->
    <input type="text" id="defaultRegisterFormSetList" class="form-control mb-4" name="setlist" placeholder="Set List">
    <!-- Genre - Musician -->
    <input type="text" id="defaultRegisterFormGenre" class="form-control mb-4" name="genre" placeholder="Genre">
    <!-- Price - Musician -->
    <input type="text" id="defaultRegisterFormPrice" class="form-control mb-4" name="price" placeholder="Price">
  </ul>
```

I am not sure how to show the ul only when checkbox is checked and hide it other wise. This is a Angular 6 project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h1>Are you a musician?</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="switch">
    <input [(ngModel)]=‘checkboxValue’ name="isMusician" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

```
  <ul *ngIf=‘checkboxValue’ id="musicianField">
<!-- Set List - Musician -->
<input type="text" id="defaultRegisterFormSetList" class="form-control mb-4" name="setlist" placeholder="Set List">
<!-- Genre - Musician -->
<input type="text" id="defaultRegisterFormGenre" class="form-control mb-4" name="genre" placeholder="Genre">
<!-- Price - Musician -->
<input type="text" id="defaultRegisterFormPrice" class="form-control mb-4" name="price" placeholder="Price">
```

Basically bind checkbox to ngmodel and basing on the value show or hide the ul

Comment: Can you please add a name property to checkbox and check